# How to set a background image to a button via CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, input, background

I have the following HTML:

```
<button id='addEVENT' class='normal b-all'></button>
```

And this CSS:

```
#addEVENT { 
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
    background:#EEEEEE url('icons/444444/pencil.png') no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

The 'normal' class adjusts the font style and the 'b-all' adds a border to replace the ugly default ones. The colour shows but not the image, I have tried many variations of CSS but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can inspect element and see what styles are applied (right click - inspect element). Also check that url to image is relative to your css file.

Comment: Hi antejan, thanks for the suggestion, I've tried this and there doesn't appear to be any issues with the applied styles, and the image is being accessed correctly.

Comment: Try removing the `fixed` property

Comment: Thank you Musa! That has solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The path `icons/444444/pencil.png` is relative to the location of the CSS file. Assuming that the CSS is inside `css/`, this would mean that you are pointing to `css/icons/444444/pencil.png`.

If this is not correct, modify the path accordingly (e.g. `../icons/444444/pencil.png`).

Comment: Hi Jon, yeah the image is inside `/css` and is therefore being pointed to and accessed correctly.